# Android "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity" exception

Tags: android, exception, instantiationexception

I am getting this error.
Problem is that the "caused by" clause doesnt seem to give any more information.

```
12-25 19:34:05.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28888): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.pro/ui.YanivMultiPlayerClientActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: ui.YanivMultiPlayerClientActivity
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: ui.YanivMultiPlayerClientActivity
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
12-25 19:34:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28888):    ... 11 more
12-25 19:34:05.110: E/SemcCheckin(28888): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your `ui.YanivMultiPlayerClientActivity` have a public parameterless constructor? It looks like it's failing to instantiate it. Reasons that might be the case:

- The class could be abstract (as it turns out is the case)
- The class could have no parameterless constructors
- A parameterless constructor could exist, but not be public
- The constructor could be throwing an exception (which I'd expect to be included as a further cause)
- The class could be an inner class that was not declared *static*.

Comment: It has the standard "public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" constructor. I commented out all the code except for the "super" and it still fails.

Comment: Sorry. My mind was miles away. I have no constructor defined so I assume it is using the default one.

Comment: @theblitz: Can you create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem (as close as possible in Android)?

Comment: Solved! Seems that my class had been changed to abstract when I was playing around with the interfaces it implements. Grrrr.

Comment: @theblitz Great Comment, Helpful a lot.. please post it as answer and accept that .. cause that will be the correct solution for the same.. not the current one..

Comment: @MKJParekh Is it ok to select your own answer as correct one?

Comment: @theblitz: Yes, although I'd argue that it's not *likely* to help others (as the chances of them making the same mistake are slim). I suggest that I edit my answer to list *various* reasons this could happen.

Comment: @theblitz Yeh, I was bit stupid saying the above comment.. I should have thought another way by editing the current answer.. anyways Jon helped the correct way..